# Vue.js application architecture, focusing on reusability and scalability

Tags: javascript, vue.js, architecture, application-design

I'm working on an Application which is already build for one country. Now it is required to scale it to multiple countries (20+) with minor changes in each component. 
How to implement for making code reusable and scalable, ways I thought:

- New Repo (Independent releases, no code reuse but easily scalable)
- New Folder for each country, new files only if changes are there (Independent, Little repeated code, Looks scalable )
- Using v-if on divs to decide to show or not (Dependent releases, Highly reusable, but difficult scalability making code dirty)

App structure/Code:  There is a form whose fields and validations will change based on country. Plus few banners whose banner layout is based on country.

Would like to know how we can architect such Vue.js Application ?

Comment: why not adding i18n? https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-add-internationalization-to-a-vue-application-d9cfdcabb03b

Comment: Yes, this will be added. But by changes I meant, some divs visible to some countries and not to other.

Comment: yes, you can achieve that by using the API of the chosen i18n library, where you could check if current lang is that, or other, and just display or not the elements

Comment: @BarbuBarbu Ok, this article gives an example of Language. Do yo have any reference for lang based element display hide.

Comment: you might check the API here http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/ I haven't worked with it before

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing all the code, but if you're already using i18n to change language strings and the changes are truly minor, I think v-ifs are your best bet.

Comment: Using i18n but changes are beyond strings. There is a form whose fields and validations will change based on country, I want to make it conditional based on country (20+).  Using 20 ifs won't make code look readable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having v-ifs, I'd delegate this logic to a custom component:

Instead of:

```
<h2>Country Specific</h2>
<v-if="country=='A'>
<v-if="country=='B'>
<v-if="country=='C'>
etc...
```

Do this:

```
<h2>Country Specific</h2>
<custom-module country="currentCountry"/>
```

and group all these "per country" modules under a specific folder separate from your "global/shared" system.

Comment: Yes, till now I'm thinking on same lines. Making country wise folders/components and based on variable passed in build, importing the required components.